# List != List<int> != List<String> != List<dynamic> How do i make sure if type == list returns true in dart

Tags: flutter, list, dart, boolean

```
listType(example) {
  var x = example.runtimeType;
  if (x == List) { 
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

print(listType([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

You can swap swap x==List with x==List< int> and see the difference!!!

How do i make it so that runtimeType always returns true as long as the return type is a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the type use `is` and do not use `runtimeType` because it make `x` a type not `list<int>`, like this:

```
listType(example) {
  
  if (example is List) { //<--- here
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: if i use "is" it just always returns false.

Comment: It is "example is List". Dont use runtimeType for this since it will always just be a Type.

Comment: I updated my answer again for shorter version. @zram

Comment: And please, don't use a boolean controlling an if to choose between two other booleans.  This function bbody is just "return example is List".

Answer (score 2):

```
bool listType<T>(example){
  return example is List<T>;
}
```

example:

```
print(listType<int>([1,2,3])) //true
print(listType<dynamic>([1,2,3])) //true
print(listType([1,2,3])) //true
print(listType([1,2,"someString"])) //true
print(listType<int>([1,2,"someString"])) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check specific type of list like list of int or list of string.

you can try it like this:

```
listType(example) {
    switch(example.runtimeType){
      case List<int>:
        print("int");
        break;
      case List<String>:
        print("String");
        break;
      case List<double>:
        print("double");
        break;
    }
  }
```